# Easy access to selfmade program

Tags: execute-command

I have a program named Log. I want to run log, but normally I have to go to ~ directory and use the command `./Log` . How would I make it so that I can use the command `Log` to do the same thing, from any directory? Would I have to add it to `/usr/bin`? Thanks!

this is my ~/.profile file:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022


# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

alias log=/home/sqidman310/Log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way (not the only way) is to create an alias in your bash profile.
`~/.profile`. Just add this and fill in your specific info
`alias log=/path/to/log`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55687/discussion-on-answer-by-philippos-slicher-easy-access-to-selfmade-program).